# Issue VueJS Radio Button Group with custom component and Composition API

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm looking for an example on how to code a custom component that displays a number of options as radio buttons (passed as props to the custom component), of which only one radio button is selected at the time and with two-way binding.
I also need this using the Composition API.

I have this custom component at the moment:

```
<template>
    <Label :label="fieldLabel" :required="required" />
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <input type="radio" :value="item.id" @input="$emit('input:model', $event.target.value)">
        {{ item.label }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from '@/firebase/config'
import { onMounted, ref } from '@vue/runtime-core';

import Label from './Label'

export default {
    name: 'RadioInput',
    components: {
        Label
    },
    props: ['item', 'label', 'model', 'sortby', 'sortorder'],
    emits: ['input:model'],
    setup(props) {
        const fieldLabel = props.label ? props.label : null
        const item = props.item
        const items = ref([])
        const model = props.model;
        const required = props.required !== undefined ? props.required : false;
        const sortBy = props.sortby !== undefined ? props.sortby : 'label';
        const sortOrder = props.sortorder !== undefined ? props.sortorder : 'asc';

        onMounted(() => {
            // Get the collection from firestore
            db.collection(item).orderBy(sortBy, sortOrder).get()
                .then(res => {
                    items.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
                        return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
                    })
                })
        })

        return { fieldLabel, items, model, required }
    }
}
</script>
```

The items are fetched from a Firebase collection, which works perfectly fine. My issue is that I can check all radio buttons individually and they all stay checked. And the selected value is not bound.

An example of the use of the custom radio group input component I have is like this:

```
<RadioInput :label="'Commercial Status'" :item="'commercial_status'" :sortby="'sort_order'" :sortorder="'asc'" v-model:model="commercialStatusId" :required="false" />
```

The result before selection looks like this:

[image]

But then I can check all radio buttons, and only one should be checked at the same time:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Radios not mutually exclusive

This part is not a Vue problem - it is pure HTML ...

[Defining a radio group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#defining_a_radio_group)

> A radio group is defined by giving each of radio buttons in the group the same `name`. Once a radio group is established, selecting any radio button in that group automatically deselects any currently-selected radio button in the same group.

#### Binding

When using [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings) with `radio`, it uses `checked` property and `change` event. You are not binding `checked` and you are handling `@input` instead of `@change`

On top of that, your component is using `model` prop and is emitting `input:model` event (to parent), but `v-model` on [custom components](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model) is expecting `modelValue` prop and `update:modelValue` event

Comment: You're absolutely right Michal, thanks. I was too much assuming it had to do with Vue. By assigning a dummy value to the name attribute of the input, I can now only select 1 value. However, the two-way binding isn't working yet, i.e. the default setting isn't happening based on model (even though model has the right value). Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out. For the default checking I had to add and data-bind the checked attribute. The following code is properly working:

```
<input type="radio" name="myDummyGroupingName" :checked="item.id==model" class="shadow" :value="item.id" @input="$emit('update:model', $event.target.value)">
```

plus 'update' instead of 'input' in the script:

```
emits: ['update:model']
```